# Issues with link on Watir and Safari?

Tags: ruby, safari, watir, safariwatir

I am new in using watir but I can only imagine this to be a bug:

> > require "watir"
> >     Watir::Browser.default = 'safari'
> >     b = Watir::Browser.new
> >     b.goto()
> >     => nil
> >     b.link(:title, "Start").click

Leads me to the next page as expected but on the following page no link works even they are there

> > b.link(:title, "Do something").exist?
> >     => true

When I then enter

> > b.link(:title, "Do something").click
> >     nothing happens, even the href attribute of course links to the next page (to be more precise, it is the same page but different request parameters)

Identifying the link with :xpath looks similar.
The same thing works fine with "firefox" as browser.

I use Safari 5.0.1, ruby 1.8.7 and installed beside others safariwatir-0.3.8

---

In fact controlling safari partially works but I have no glue why it hangs on the second page. Here is an example using a scenario in the internet:

this works fine:

> > browser.goto("http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/dn?S=Frankfurt(Main)Hbf&Z=Nrnberg%20Hbf&date=%2B30&time=1500&start=1&")
> >     => nil

this also works fine - the link does exist:

> > browser.link(:title, /Mit Tickets zum Normalpreis/).exist?
> >     => true

this does not work - the browser window stays unchanged:

> > browser.link(:title, /Mit Tickets zum Normalpreis/).click
> >     => nil

I would like to try fire_event or fireEvent but irb says invalid method. I guess the hints I found about firing an event are outdated?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to drive Safari is to use [safariwatir gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/safariwatir) (works only on Mac OS X). Try this (from [SafariWatir](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/SafariWatir) wiki page at [Watir](http://watir.com/) [wiki](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Project+Home)):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'safariwatir'
browser = Watir::Safari.new
browser.goto("http://google.com")
```

Comment: Thanx for your feedback. I tried the additional 'safariwatir' require but no change. I precised my answer below

Comment: Please post your script in the whole. I do not understand what is the problem. Also, do not require watir, just safariwatir.